# Does WiFi Router/AP change the working channel automatically during the normal use?

Tags: wireless

I'm sure a lot of AP or WiFi modem/router can perform an autoscan to select the best channel to be used during the boot.

Is the channel selection also performed in other situations (other than device boot)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a general truth, but some WiFi Routers/ AP's do change the channel without rebooting. Some reasons include, but not limit to:

- Noisy environment on specific channel
- Lots of other AP's on the same channel
- Interference with Bluetooth and/or other RF Communication
- Intrusion Prevention/Detection Systems trigger such as routers sensing that the WPS PIN is being bruteforced by Reaver or other tools
- Another AP with the same ESSID (name) on that channel

Please note that this behavior is very manufacturer specific / firmware specific, for example some Open Source Firmware such as OpenWRT or DD-WRT can be configured to hop channels based on user defined conditions

Answer (score 4):

If your AP want to use a 5 GHz channel which is also used by radars, it NEED to support Dynamic Frequency Selection (DFS for short).

In that case, it may perform a survey on the target 5 GHz channel to check the presence of radar pulses, then may start using it, while still checking for radars.

If a radar pulse is detected after the AP has started, it sends a Channel Switch Announcement telling the stations that the AP will change channel after the next X beacons.  The stations must obey or they will be disconnected.

Of course, the channel switch mechanism may also be used for other purpose than to switch away from a radar channel.